# Why the $ -x$ in the expression $(-x^2y^3)^2$ becomes positive when simplified in accordance of the rules of exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this expression $(-x^2y^3)^4$ which results in $x^8y^12$ when simplified in accordance of the third law of the exponents rules which is $(a^m)^n = a^{mn}$.

Why the $-x$ becomes positive when the exponent $4$ multiplied by its exponent which is $2$ ? Is it because $4$ is a natural, even number, the $-x$ is simplified to positive $x$ directly ?

Comment: $(-1)^4=1$ just like the others got raised to the 4th. $(x^2)^4=x^8$ and $(y^3)^4=y^{12}$

Comment: @randomgirl That is the -x = -1 ?

Comment: See the answer below. Maybe @RolfHoyer made his answer more readable than my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you factor $-x^2y^3$ as $(-1)x^2y^3$, then you have $((-1)x^2y^3)^4 = (-1)^4 (x^2)^4(y^3)^4 = (1)(x^8)(y^{12}) = x^8y^{12}$.  Hopefully this shows that any time you take an even power of something, you discard any factor of $-1$.

Comment: Which means -x^2 is actually exactly as -1^4 since x = 1 ?

Comment: Wait, why is x=1?

Comment: We can't make assumptions that $x=1$. If you want leave the - on the $x^2$. It doesn't matter. $(-x^2)^4=(-x^2)(-x^2)(-x^2)(-x^2)$ . You are multiplying a negative number an even amount of times the results will be positive. $(-x^2)^4=x^{2+2+2+2}=x^{8}$

Comment: Ah! now that makes sense so we're multiplying the negative x itself which results in positive x.

Comment: Your last statement (the "Ah!" one) is one way to think about it. But realize that whenever you see $-x$ or $-3$ or $-whatever$, you can interpret it as $-1 \times x$ or $-1 \times 3$ or $-1 \times whatever$. Reread Rolf's answer, and you'll see this is just what he did. He factored out the $-1$ and brought it to the fourth power. Hence $-1^4 =1$.

Answer (score 0):

x^2 would surely be a positive number(or 0). So -x^2 would surely be a negative number(or zero). Now, (-x^2)^4 would surely be a positive number(or zero). We can directly arrive at the last conclusion because any real number raised to an even power is positive (or zero).